# RedirectMatch 301 in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can anyone tell me what does

```
RedirectMatch 301 /([a-zA-Z_]+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-1-([a-z]+)-([a-zA-Z_]+).html http://www.example.com/$1-$2-$3-$4-$5.html
```

mean in .htaccess file??

Comment: Please don't treat SO as `explain-my-code` forum.  What problem are you facing?

Comment: on my website the URL doesn't exist, but server is not returning a 404 (file not found) error. Instead its returning 301 Moved Permanently HTTP status code.when I checked my htaccess file...the above regex was written

Comment: For which URL you're getting 301 and what is your expected behavior?

Comment: i juz need to know what wil the above regex do in dis case?

Comment: Above regex won't match `/collection-861-1-british_campaign_teak_table_with_folding_extensions.html` hence 301 is not from the above rule.

Comment: Then what can be done to redirect the url /collection-861-1-british_campaign_teak_table_with_folding_extensions.html properly

Comment: Sure it can be done but where do you want to redirect above URL to?

Comment: The above url does not exists...so it shld show http status 404. Instead of that in WebMasters tools its showing 301 Moved permanently. How can a proper error message be shown

Comment: `301 Moved ` to which target URL?

Answer (score 0):

This regex is searching for:
**[anyChars and_]-[digits]-[digits]-1-[smallChars and_]-[anyChars and_].html**
and redirects browser. Ex:

*aaAA-1234-567-1-bbb-cC_c.html*
will be redirected to:
*http://www.example.com/aaAA-1234-567-bbb-cC_c.html*

Also here is a good service to test RegEx: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/